# kubectl output for READY

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

By default, `kubectl get pods` outputs

```
NAME                                                              READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
my-podob-6f7f9d798c-grhmd                                       1/1     Running        0          6d17h
```

Now I'd like to add a few extra columns to this, so I've set up a template.txt file with:

```
NAME          IMAGES
metadata.name metadata.annotations.imageTag
```

I can't seem to figure out how `READY` is calculated from the output.  Ideally, I would append to the `get pods` output with a few custom columns but I can't tell if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a FR for appending extra columns [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71612).

The "READY" column is a special case in the source: [printers.go#L558](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L558) and its value is calculated in the implementation.

Unfortunately it seems that it's impossible to "count things" both in JSONPath and Go templates.

Maybe consider creating an alias to run the ordinary `kubectl get pods` and then the one with your custom columns?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be:

```
NAME          IMAGES                         READY  
metadata.name metadata.annotations.imageTag .status.containerStatuses[*].ready
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it does not produce the same output as mentioned above.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't show numbers but it gives the same functionality